# Dump data from segments.io /segment.com with apikey

Tags: dump

I am analyzing an app and in it's data I found an apikey for segments.io.
Using this apikey, is it possible to see what data is stored or perhaps even dump it?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. The API endpoint is `https://api.segment.io/` - it seems to be a REST interface. You can find the software documentation [here](https://segment.com/docs/).

Also there seems to be a broad range of integrations to parse and read the data [here](https://segment.com/catalog#integrations/all).

Please also know that the system uses a WriteKey and a ReadKey apparently, but I can not deduce which one you have.

> If you want to write your own REST client, please refer to
>   StackOverflow for programming-guidance. This SE community is dedicated
>   to reverse engineering.